# How to read calendar events with different time zone Change

Tags: android, calendar, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

i am working on a device calendar events. The person installed the app was in India, now he is in US. when he open the app the it gives him the bank screen, how can i fix this issue can any one tell me.
app works in the indian time zone. in US time zone like Sunnyvale app gives blank screen.

here is the code how i am retrieving the events from the calendar.

```
 long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Uri.Builder eventsUriBuilder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
    ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, Long.MIN_VALUE);
    ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    String[] projection = new String[]{CalendarContract.Instances.CALENDAR_ID, CalendarContract.Instances.TITLE,
            CalendarContract.Instances.DESCRIPTION, CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN,
            CalendarContract.Instances.END, CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_LOCATION,
            CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_ID};

    Uri eventsUri = eventsUriBuilder.build();
    Cursor instance_cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            eventsUri, projection, CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN + " >= " + now + " and " + CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN
                    + " <= " + (now + 2592000000L) + " and " + CalendarContract.Instances.VISIBLE + " = 1",
            null, CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART + " ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issues by converting the time zone with the date format like this:

```
Date datee=  new Date(instance_cursor.getLong(3));
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
String date = formatter.format(datee).toString().replace("/"," ");
Log.d(TAG, "instance date"+date);
Log.d(TAG, "device date"+devicedate);
```

With the code above, I am able to get events and instances of irrespective of time zones.